# How to use higher order functions effectively?

Tags: haskell

By utilizing higher order functions, what is the best way to implement the function `makeCloths`?
What I'm hoping to achieve is that `makeCloths` can automatically populate each method in the `methodsList` with the correct arguments that is provided in the `materialList`.  So that in the future if more methods are added to the `methodsList`, and the methods uses only the arguments in `materialList`, we don't need to modify the code in `makeCloths`.

```
data Material = WhiteCloth Int
              | BlueCloth Int
              | RedCloth Int

makeWhiteShirt :: Material -> Clothe
makeWhiteShirt (WhiteCloth x) = .....

makeBluePants :: Material -> Clothe
makeBluePants (BlueCloth x) = .....

makeRedBlueDress :: Material -> Material -> Clothe
makeRedBlueDress (RedCloth x) (BlueCloth y) = ......

methodsList = [ makeWhiteShirt, makeBluePants, makeRedBlueDress ]
materialList = [ WhiteCloth 3, BlueCloth 2, RedCloth 2]

-- call makeCloths like so
-- listOfClothes = makeCloths methodsList materialList 
makeCloths :: [a] -> [b] -> [Clothe]
```

Comment: How is `Clothe` defined? Is this code your own work or taken from an assignment?

Comment: There's a problem here, in that `makeWhiteShirt` has type `Material -> Clothe` and `makeRedBlueDress` has type `Material -> Material -> Clothe`, so they can't both go in the same list (everything in a list must have the same type). Also, what happens if I call `makeWhiteShirt` with the argument `RedCloth 1`? Does that give an error?

Comment: #Chris's question, that's one of the problem I encountered....I don't know what's the best way to have a bunch of information and bunch of methods that uses the information differently...how do the methods actually find the arguments that's in the information list

Comment: Maybe you could have each of the constructor functions take a list of available materials, so each signature was `[Material] -> Clothe` or perhaps `[Material] -> Maybe Clothe`, if you are not sure that the available materials can make a piece of cloth.

Comment: #Boris, I'm currently making a finance side project and I've got meany methods that calculate stuff using fixed data like equity, assets, this year profit, last year profit etc...well I'm thinking makeCloths should only call the methods with the right arguments

Comment: What does the `Int` in `BlueCloth Int` mean. Is it how many metres of cloth you have, or is it how blue a given piece of cloth is? What happens if you have a list with a `BlueCloth 4` element, and no other `BlueCloth` elements? Can `makeBluePants` and `makeBlueRedDress` both use this element, or is there a conflict?

Comment: Well I think it would mean how blue the cloth is.  And for makeBlueRedDress if there is only BlueCloth and no RedCloth then makeCloths would call makeBlueRedDress with only BlueCloth and makeBlueRedDress should throw error or maybe we should change it to Maybe Clothe and return Nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, as many others have suggested, haskell wouldn't allow you to have an array of functions whose cardinality don't match. You would want to make makeRedBlueDress to be of type Material -> Clothe. If you really want this kind of polymorphism, nothing stops us from defining additional type for Material that takes multiple arguments (or composed of multiple Materials)

Once we have that, makeCloths is a special case of zipWith function.

```
makeCloths = zipWith $ \x y -> (x y)
```

The type signature for it makes the most sense

```
zipWith $ \x y -> (x y) :: [b -> c] -> [b] -> [c]
```

Comment: Wow! That is really close to what I'm looking to do.  However, for your model a method can only have one argument, if a method needs multiple arguments we would have to modify the data type to accompany it.  But that would not be flexible when we want to change the methodsList often or dynamically.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Its very hard to put functions with different arity into the same category. You might be better off designing all functions to accept multiples of arguments by accepting an array, then do a clever pattern matching.